# Python setup.py create namespace without corresponding directory

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a library with the following structure:

```
├── mylib
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── tools
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── py_script
│   └── __init__.py
```

and I would like to do an editable pip install such that I can use `mylib` in other code like

```py
from mylib.tools import useful_tool
```

and run `py_script` from the command line.

Is there a way to add a setup.py file to `mylib` that would allow for this import behavior without having to update the directory structure (e.g. moving everything into a new `mylib/mylib` folder)?

The reason for the constraint is that many people have been using `mylib` by manually adding the parent directory (e.g. `mylib/...`) to `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` to get the import behavior above and I would prefer to not break that workflow.

Comment: maybe see how to use `__all__` in this case

Comment: @sahasrara62 From looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) on `__all__`, it seems it only restricts what gets imported when calling `import *` but it doesn't impact the syntax for importing from a project/package.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was trying to find. Thank you!